# Connecting to Sphinx from sql server linked server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, sphinx, linked-server

I am trying to connect to Sphinx from SQL Server Management Studio as a Linked server. I tried the following query:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server=N'SPHINX_SEARCH', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @provstr=N'Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Port=9306,charset=UTF8;User=;Password=;OPTION=3'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'SPHINX', @useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
GO
```

And i am getting the following exception:

> **Title: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
>
> The test connection to the linked server failed.
>
> **Additional information**
>
> The OLE DB providcer "MSDASQL" for linked server "SPHINX_SEARCH" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SPHINX_SEARCH". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399).

While connecting to Sphinx from MySQL is working via the following command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306
```

Any suggestions?

---

*Sphinx version: 3.0.3, SQL server version: 2014, MySQL version: 5.6*

Comment: try this: "Be made using login current security context" 3rd option in Linked sever properties and set @useself is to "true"

Comment: @CR241 still not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested with Manticore, but should work with Sphinx too:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'Search',
@srvproduct=N'manticore', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'manticore',
@provstr=N'Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=9306,charset=UTF8;User=;Password=;'
```

`manticore` is System DSN name set in ODBC Administrator.

In sphinx.conf you need to set **mysql_version_string**  to 5.1.1  (or anything greater than 4.1.1) to replace the actual daemon version. Otherwise the ODBC driver will refuse to work with the searchd daemon (because sees server version as being too old).

**Update based on comments**

The issue was solved after installing the latest Sphinx release 3.1.1. There was some bug related to MySQL client in release 3.0.3.

Comment: There is no system DSN defined in the ODBC administrator, also connection cannot be established to the port 9306 (from ODBC administrator). Only connection can be made using a command prompt console

Comment: Note that i can create a System DSN to connect to the mysql engine port (3306), but  not for Sphinx (9306)

Comment: `Unknown MySQL Error`

Comment: try latest version. There was some bug related to mysql 8 client.

Comment: The issue was solved after installing the latest Sphinx release 3.1.1. And sorry because the bounty was awarded by the system to the answer before that i tried you suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check in SQL Server Management Studio under "Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers" if your MSDASQL Provider is listed here and is installed properly?

Also you could try to open the properties for this provider and check the "allow inprocess" option there and check again if you can connect.

You also might want to check this link for further things you can try:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2450479/you-get-7399-and-7300-error-messages-when-accessing-a-linked-server

Comment: MSDASQL is installed properly and `allow inprocess` is already checked.